# Syntactic sugar for knowing if all array elements return true for specific method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

In my Ruby program, I have an array of five strings, and I want to check if each one of the elements of that array match to a given requirement, for example:

```
a = ['', '', '', '']
a.inject(:blank?) # Will return true if (and only if) all elements of a are blank
```

I'm asking this question because Ruby has a pretty large standard API with a lot of pre-written syntactical sugar, which I want to know and don't want to reinvent.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a very concise way:

```
array.all? &:blank?
```

Study [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html) and learn how to use [`Enumerator`s](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html) and you'll be speaking the most pleasant dialect of Ruby in no time.

Comment: Thank you, that's **exactly** what I wanted :D

Comment: Note that `blank?` is not part of the Ruby core, and comes from ActiveSupport's core extensions (which are included in Rails).

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative way: if you have String#to_proc (search it because I would not post my own depository site in case being considered as ads), you can use a similar way you have:

`a.inject(&'&& $1.blank?')`

which is equivalent to

```
a.inject{ |sum,i|
  sum && i.blank?
}
```

Comment: Generally speaking, [it is fine](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) to post your own projects if they happen to provide a relevant answer to the question. There are many discussions about this on meta, read them if you want to know more about the etiquette.